# How to go from a symbolic expression to a vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am working on a function that will generate polynomial interpolants for a given set of ordered pairs.  You currently input the indexes of the node points in one vector, and the values of the function to be interpolated in a second vector.  I then generate a symbolic expression for the Lagrange polynomial that interpolates that set of points.  I would like to be able to go from this symbolic form to a vector form for comparison with test functions and such.  That is, I have something that generates some polynomial P(x) in terms of some symbolic variable x.  I would like to then sample this polynomial to a vector, and get values for the polynomial over (for example) linspace(-1,1,1000).  If this is possible, how do I do it?

I guess I'll include the code that I have so far:

```
function l_poly = lpoly(x,f)
%   Returns the polynomial interpolant as computed by lagrange's formula
syms a
n=size(x,2);
l_poly_vec = 1;
l_poly=0;
for k=1:n,
    for l=1:n,
        if (k ~= l)
            l_poly_vec=l_poly_vec*(a-x(l))/(x(k)-x(l));
        end
    end
    l_poly=l_poly+f(k)*l_poly_vec;
    l_poly_vec = 1;
end
```

I plan on adding a third (or possibly fourth) input depending on how I can solve this issue.  I'm guessing I would just need the length of the vector I want to sample to and the endpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you've constructed a Lagrange interpolating polynomial using the symbolic toolbox and now wish to evaluate it over a vector of values.   One way to do this is to use the function **[sym2poly](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/sym2poly.html)** to extract the coefficients of the symbolic polynomial, and then use **[polyval](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/polyval.html)** to evaluate it.   Alternatively, you could use [matlabFunction](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/matlabfunction.html) to convert your symbolic expression into a regular Matlab function; or use [subs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/subs.html) to substitute in a numeric value for 'x'.

However, you would probably be better off avoiding the symbolic toolbox altogether and directly constructing the coefficients of the Lagrange interpolating polynomial, or, better yet, use a different interpolation scheme altogether.  The function **[interp1](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/interp1.html)** might be a good place to start.